# Scala : How to create Unit test case in Intellij

Tags: scala, scalatest

Could you help me in the process of creating Unit Test case for Scala in IntelliJ?

I tried creating it using intention action but it did not come for me. I checked the settings also for intention. All looks fine to me.

Do we have different process for Scala or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think if you right click on a name (class, method, etc.) and select 'go to/test' (which i think is bound to Ctrl-Shift-T in the default keymap), it will offer to create a missing test.